# How to pass parameter when I redirect the page after insert in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

i am not getting how to redirect my page after inert query

I tried to redirect in script

any help would be appriciated

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){    
    $scope.insertData=function(){      
        $http.post("test.php", {
            'bname':$scope.bname
             'id':$scope.id
        }).then(function(response){
                console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                location.href="index.php";  
            },function(error){
                alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                console.error(error);

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Using this code, my page is redirecting on index page, after data inserted.
But I want to pass id on the index page

Comment: I highly recommend using a routing system instead of setting `location.href`, but couldn't you simply add it as a querystring parameter? i.e. `location.href="index.php?id=" + $scope.id;`

Comment: But what if I want to pass the variable which is in test.php file. Like i'm generating uniqid in test.php and inserting it in databasse. <?php  $queid= uniqid();  ?> and I want to pass this id to index page instead of $scope.id

Comment: You would do the same thing as above but use the response object `location.href="index.php?id=" + response.data.uniqid;`